# Code running fine in Chrome Console but not in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am starting a Chrome extension to hide and modify some content on pages of a website.

The code is very simple for the moment :

```
manifest.json

{
"name":"External",
"description":"Adapted content",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.mywebsite.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["test_chrome.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And my JS :

```
test_chrome.js

element = document.querySelector('div.bidder');
element.remove();
```

When I load the page the div is still here, but when I type in my two lines of JS in the Chrome Console, the div is removed just like I want.

I get the following error in the Console when I load the page :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null at test_chrome.js:2

(anonymous) @ test_chrome.js:2

I actually manage to remove the header or the wrapper of the page with the extension, but I cannot remove any other div with the extension (though it works in the Console).
I have already tried to change the run_at property, but did not get my code to work.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: It means the site is adding that element after the content script runs. This is common with the modern sites that fetch some data from their servers and put into the page on response. You can use MutationObserver or simply run the code in setInterval until the element appears, then clear the interval.

Comment: You probably just need to make it run after the document loads.  Change `"run_at": "document_idle"` to `"run_at": "document_end"`

Comment: document_idle fires after document_end so it won't help.

Comment: Indeed setInterval or timer do work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try something like:

```
let x = setInterval(()=>{ 
element = document.querySelector('div.bidder');
 if (element) {
  element.remove()
  clearInterval(x);
 }
}, 3000);
```

and run at start instead of end or idle.